# If a range contains dates greater then a given date?

Tags: vba, date

I have a range of observations in a given time period. I want to execute an action for all observations that are after 12/31/2015 and between 01/01/2015 - 12/31/2015. I suppose I need an "If" function but I have difficulty expressing the date range.

This is one of my versions of the code which doesn't work:

```
If Range("b:b") > "Date(2015,12,31)" Then
If Range("b:b") >= "Date(2015,1,1)" <= "Date(2015,12,31)" Then
```

I need the code to work with any date format regardless of the regional settings of the computer. I have tried many different ways to express this correctly but non of them has worked.

My questions regards only the way to express the condition of the "If". I know how to write the code after "Then".

Any attempt to help solve my problem will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, even with different date localizations:

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(1)

With ws
    For Each c In .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(10, 2))
        If IsDate(c) And c > DateValue(#12/31/2015#) Then
            If c >= DateValue(#1/1/2015#) And c <= (#12/31/2015#) Then
                MsgBox "hi"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Note though, that your conditions dont make that much sense. You first look for dates after the 31.12.2015 and then for dates before or equal to the 31.12.2015.